# Locales set to unexisting ones

Tags: kubuntu, locale, konsole

I am using Kubuntu (Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS)

```
$uname -a
Linux mobile2 3.13.0-37-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Mon Sep 22 21:30:01 UTC 2014 i686 i686 i686 GNU/Linux)
```

I am facing a very strange problems with locales in Konsole (the KDE's terminal emulator) program .If I login to a normal console it does not exists.

I have set my locale to Bulgarian (bg_BG), however recently I started to receive garbled output in the console when Cyrillic characters were used, even my Thunderbird couldn't work with folders with Cyrillic names.

It turns out that my locales are somehow messed up. Here is what I get from the `locale` command:

```
$locale
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_BG.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en:bg:es:en
LC_CTYPE="en_BG.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_BG.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_BG.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_BG.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

As you may guess, there is not such locale as `en_BG`. I have the correct settings in `/etc/default/locale`.

```
$cat /etc/default/locale 
LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="bg_BG.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="bg_BG.UTF-8
```

If I login as root (I have root enabled), the `locale` settings are OK, and the console works fine. I am not doing any manual exports of variables, and I could not find why the locales are in such garbled state.

I have tried to reinstall language packs, regenerate locales and searched in various dot files in my home directory but I haven't found anything pointing to where the problem might be.

Any ideas what can mess up my locales in this strange way?

Comment: Have you checked the ~/.kde/env/setlocale.sh ? A bug report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1322968

Comment: That is exactly the problem, 10x.

Comment: I'm not using Kubuntu myself, but I think there is a way in the GUI to change the language separately, i.e. you ought to be able to change it to Bulgarian, and with that get valid locale names.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [this question](http://askubuntu.com/q/501181/63516).