# Locale troubles

Tags: kde, locale

I'm having trouble fixing my locale settings. A similar question has been posted earlier here:

[How do I fix my locale issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue)

But it proved unhelpful. My problem is not that the locale is not installed on my system, as most answers seem to suggest. Details:

```
$ locale-gen "nb_NO.UTF-8"
Generating locales...
  nb_NO.UTF-8... up-to-date
Generation complete.
$ update-locale LC_ALL="nb_NO.UTF-8"
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = "en",
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "en_NO.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_NO.UTF-8"
are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

I am guessing my problem is related to either KDE or having a different OS language than my local language (I want everything to be in english, but have norwegian keyboard settings, currency etc).

I think this problem arose after changing some settings in the system settings dialog a while back, bug?

Comment: Some more surfing revealed this question:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/501181/how-to-change-fix-systems-locale-when-you-setup-in-a-language-not-official-in-y?rq=1

which in turn seems to be related to this bug:

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1322968

Answer (score 1):

I managed to temporarily fix the issue by changing the system language from American English to British English.

I did it via the KDE System Settings > Locale > Languages dialog. Amusingly, it displayed an error message saying that replacing the current language was not permitted, but in practice it was since the new settings were applied when I hit the "apply" button, and restarted the machine.

Leaving question open until bug is fixed. Current local output:

```
$ locale
LANG=en_GB.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en
LC_CTYPE="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="nb_NO.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=nb_NO.UTF-8
```

Comment: I'm a little curious about how you fixed it. Can you please show us the output of the `locale` command after having made that change? (Can mention that I too filed a [related bug report](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1395401) a while ago.)

Comment: Edited the answer. It does seem, however strange, that something "special" happens with en_US at the top there. In detail, in the GUI dialog I mentioned, I added british english to the right hand list, then removed american english from the right hand list, ignored the error msg, then apply and restart.

Comment: I would try `sudo sed -i '/LC_ALL/d' /etc/default/locale` (and reboot) to get rid of the `LC_ALL` entry. You should never set `LC_ALL` persistently on a desktop.