# How to fix "en_DE.UTF-8" (locales) warnings?

Tags: kde, settings, language-support, locale

On my system I am getting errors(?) like this:

```
bash: warning: setlocale: LC_CTYPE: cannot change locale (en_DE.UTF-8)
```

or

```
weemonger@awesomeLinuxSystem:~$ dpkg-reconfigure locales
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en:de:en",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_DE.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_DE.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

**How do I fix my system an get rid of the locale warnings/errors?**

I have to say, that I living in Germany and **use the english (*en*) language for my system**, but also I have configured my system **to use the german (*DE*) formats/norms** for Numbers, Money, Measurements, Page size, etc.
I did this using the *KDE Control Module* `Country/Region & Language`.

---

I think I got rid of the warnings by myself, so I will post an answer myself, but wait some time before I accept it, as I didn't fully grok/understand it.

Answer (score 16):

Ok, here is what I assume:

I set up KDE to use the english (*en*) language but german (*DE*) formats, therefore it tries to set my locale to a combination of both: **en_DE**.
Like any *british user* would get **en_UK** and *someone from New Zealand* **en_NZ**.
But unfortunately noone(?) ever(?) created a locale definition for my combination: **en_DE**.

So all the warnings are correct and simple say, that there isn't a locale **en_DE** on my system and it can't be found anywhere.
After getting this insight by some googling, I made sure all necessary(?) locales are installed on my system:

```
sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8 de_DE de_DE.UTF-8
```

And defined that, *en_DE.UTF-8* should use the same locale definition as *de_DE*:

```
sudo localedef -i de_DE -f UTF-8 en_DE.UTF-8
```

A subsequent `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales` did no longer produce any warnings/errors and I hope, that I have fixed this annoyance.

As I mentioned in my question, I don't understand/grok the problem fully and didn't read any man pages or other official resources about locales (shame on me and I should go *rtfm*), so **I don't know**, if I really fixed my problem and didn't introduce some new by this **questionable** `localedef` call.

Hopefully someone will enlighten me and/or point the corresponding *fine* manual.
At least I hope, this answer help some others, who have also this strange locale *en_DE* and googling didn't help within the first results.

Comment: Strange. I think this could be a bug of KDE, because I also use English language with German formats on Unity Desktop, and I have no problems here. It did not create such an invalid locale like `en_DE` here. You should consider writing a bug report against KDE. See [how-do-i-report-a-bug](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug)

Comment: @ByteCommander: After  I wrote the question, I saw a similar question in the *Related* question box, [there](http://askubuntu.com/a/518149/476544) it is said this is a reported bug.    
If you could mark this question as a duplicate of the other one, I would be glad.    
Maybe I should ask/read more about my `localedef` solution, and decide if this a possible workaround.

Comment: Ok, voted to close. But you could have clicked the `close` link below your question yourself as well.

Comment: Thank you, sorry I didn't know about the close feature - I was looking for "mark as duplicated" and didn't want to delete the question. The more you know ;)