# Why are Chrome-based Browsers Unicode-named files downloaded as "download", can this be fixed?

Tags: 22.04, google-chrome

Ever since some time in Februrary any Chrome-based Browsers on my Linux PC (Kubuntu 22.04) will no longer download files with Unicode-characters (e.g. if they contain any Japanese characters) normally, but instead will download them as "download".

Neither does this happen on Windows, nor does Firefox have this problem.
what could be the Reason?

when downloading via chrome.downloads.download through an extension downlaods with target paths in the aforementioned way (including folder names) will just be blocked with the error "invalid filename"

Comment: Can you share an example URL / download that fails?

Comment: https://my1.dev/%E3%81%AB%E3%82%83%E3%82%93.bin
for example, just a file with the word test in it. (.bin is just to force the browser to DL it)
normally it should download as にゃん.bin

Comment: This is rather odd. How were these browsers installed? (Snap/Deb/Flatpak/compiled from source). I'm not seeing this with my installation of 22.04 with Chrome or Edge 

Comment: weirdly enough I think this wasnt an issue in January either but only in feb. maybe something else is screweing with the browsers. I installed them as deb as that's what I usually do.
is there a way to get some logs off of chrome mayve it can shed some light

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this. I put a file called `にゃん.bin` on my server and then downloaded it using Edge. I'm on 23.04 with Edge 111.0.1661.62 installed via deb.

Comment: I think I have something, apparently when setting up ubuntu with english language but german Regional stuff it sets the locale to `en_DE.UTF-8` and chrome doesnt quite seem to like that forcing LC_ALL to en_US.UTF-8 seems to have the problem disappear, fun part tho is how to get the locale settings to work in the way I want, locale-gen doesnt let me generate the locale sadly.

Comment: Update: after searching around a bit more you can use localedef to make that locale, see here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/710955/how-to-fix-en-de-utf-8-locales-warnings

Comment: In case someone asks how I found that stuff, I basically went from the error code of the extension api backwards in the google chrome source code which lead me into i18n, where I then tried locale stuff