# Different UI language for week/month from default in KDE

Tags: 14.04, kde, language-support, date

I would like to have UI in English but week/month names in another language (lets say French, Spanish, Italian ,etc.)

Seems like when I set UI to English, there is no control on week/month names. I just can change calendar type and other similar settings.

This type of settings is extremely useful if your native language is not English, but you prefer to have UI in english.

I am suing KDE in Ubuntu 14.04

Update:

after running `sudo update-locale LC_TIME=it_IT.UTF-8` 
I receive this error:

```
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
        LANGUAGE = "en:it:fr:en",
        LC_ALL = (unset),
        LC_PAPER = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_ADDRESS = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_MONETARY = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_NUMERIC = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_TELEPHONE = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_IDENTIFICATION = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_MEASUREMENT = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_TIME = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LC_NAME = "en_IT.UTF-8",
        LANG = "en_IT.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
```

Update 2:
output of `local -a` (now I dont have French language selected in options any more)

```
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_COLLATE to default locale: No such file or directory
C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_AG
en_AG.utf8
en_AU.utf8
en_BW.utf8
en_CA.utf8
en_DK.utf8
en_GB.utf8
en_HK.utf8
en_IE.utf8
en_IN
en_IN.utf8
en_NG
en_NG.utf8
en_NZ.utf8
en_PH.utf8
en_SG.utf8
en_US.utf8
en_ZA.utf8
en_ZM
en_ZM.utf8
en_ZW.utf8
it_CH.utf8
it_IT.utf8
```

Comment: Strange point is in the error mentioned above, why it is "en_IT" shouldn't it "it_IT" ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Week and month names in calendars are usually controlled by the `LC_TIME` environment variable, so you need to change that. This command sets/changes `LC_TIME` in the `/etc/default/locale` file:

```
sudo update-locale LC_TIME=fr_FR.UTF-8
```

At next login, weeks/months will hopefully be displayed in French.

Edit: The Problem is related to [this bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/kde-runtime/+bug/1322968). As suggested inside the comments, **changing the default language to British English fix the issue.** 
 Also more or less the same problem is discussed [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/501181/how-to-change-fix-systems-locale-when-you-setup-in-a-language-not-official-in-y/518149#518149).

Comment: tnx for answer. after running the command, I receive an error. pls take a look at the update inside the question.

Comment: maybe I should install the local language(in this case italian) before?

Comment: @Woeistg: Your locale is broken (no en_IT.UTF-8 locale exists). Probably you hit [bug #1322968](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1322968). Can you please run the `locale -a` command in a terminal window, and show us the output by editing the question again.

Comment: I update the question. yes, it is very probable that it is the same bug.

Comment: @Woeistg: So the Italian locales are already generated. Does any of the bug comments explain how you can workaround the problem? (I don't have time right now to dig into it myself.)

Comment: I changed the default language to British English and the problem is fixed. Seems like here is a more or less the same problem: http://askubuntu.com/questions/501181/how-to-change-fix-systems-locale-when-you-setup-in-a-language-not-official-in-y/518149#518149